# Filling Riemannian manifolds, Gromov, Proposition 5.1.B

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In Gromovs paper Filling Riemannian manifolds, https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214509283 it states on page 46:

5.1.B Proposition 
Let $v$ be a surface with complete Finsler metric, fix a point $v\in V$ and let $R\in[\frac{1}{2}h(v),\frac{1}{2}Sys(V,v)]$. Then
\begin{equation}
Area \ B(v,R) \ \geq \ \frac{1}{2}(2R-h(v)).
\end{equation}
Here $Sys(V,v)$ denotes the length of a shortest noncontractible loop based at $v$ and
\begin{equation}
h(v)=\inf\{tension(\gamma)|\gamma  \ \text{is either a noncontractible loop or an infinite path through  }v\},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
tension(\gamma)=\sup\{\delta>0|\text{there is an homotopy from }\gamma \ \text{to } \overline{\gamma}, \text{s.t. } length(\overline{\gamma})=length(\gamma)-\delta\}.
\end{equation}
Now the proof works as follows:
Suppose $R<\frac{1}{2}Sys(V,v)$, then $B(v,R)$ is contractible. Thus for every connected component of its boundary $S_i\subset \partial B(v,R)$, there is a surface $D_i$ homeomorphic to a disk, s.t. $\partial D_i=S_i$. Denote by $B^+(v,R)$ the union of $B(v,r)$ with all the $D_i's$.
Let $\gamma$ be either a noncontractible loop or an infinite path through $v$. Thus $\gamma$ intersects $\partial B^+(v,R)$ at least two times. Choose the first $x_1$ and the last $x_2$ of this interesections when walking along $\gamma$. This divides $\partial B^+(v,R)$ in two parts $L_1,L_2$ with $l_1=length(L_1)\leq length(L_2)=l_2$. Now $\gamma$ is homotopic to the loop $\gamma'$ obtained by the part of $\gamma$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ union $L_1$. Thus in particular
\begin{equation}
tension(\gamma)\geq 2R-l_1,
\end{equation}
Since $\gamma'$ is at least $2R-l_1$ shorter then $\gamma$. Thus we get
\begin{equation}
tension(\gamma)\geq 2R-\frac{1}{2}length(\partial B^+(v,R)),
\end{equation}
which is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
length(\partial B^+(v,R))\geq 4R-2tension(\gamma).
\end{equation}
In the next line it says that we can thus say
\begin{equation}
length(\partial B^+(v,R))\geq 4R-2h(v).
\end{equation}
I don't see how this follows. Isn't by definition $h(v)\leq tension(\gamma)$?

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so in most cases the inequality

$$\mathrm{tens}(\gamma) ≥ 2 R - l_1$$
is going to be rather worthless, since the term $2R-l_1$ might as well be negative. You have correctly made this inequality even weaker:
$$\mathrm{len}(\partial B^+(v,R)) ≥ 4 R - 2\mathrm{tens}(\gamma)$$
The next step is not to bound $\mathrm{tens}(\gamma)≤h(v)$, this is certainly true but won't help you. Rather you want to make this weak inequality as strong as possible by looking only at those $\gamma$ where it is helpful. So you take the $\sup$ over all admissible $\gamma$:
$$\mathrm{len(\partial B^+(v,R)) = \sup_{\gamma}}\ \mathrm{len}(\partial B^+(v,R))≥ \sup_{\gamma} [4R - 2\mathrm{tens}(\gamma)] = 4R - 2\inf_\gamma\ \mathrm{tens}(v) = 4R-2h(v)$$

Comment: Now it seems clear to me, thank you!